# PostgreSQL: WHERE id = ANY (idsArray) - sort results by idsArray

Tags: database, postgresql

Is there a trick I'm missing when using a `WHERE...ANY` style query in Postgres to order the results by the given array? ie:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = ANY (<idsInDesiredOrder>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [array_position](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) can help you:

```
WITH sample (id, description) AS (
    VALUES 
        (1, 'lorem ipsum'),
        (2, 'lorem ipsum'),
        (3, 'lorem ipsum'),
        (4, 'lorem ipsum')
)
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    sample 
WHERE 
    id = ANY (ARRAY[3,2]) 
ORDER BY 
    array_position(ARRAY[3,2], id);
```

Answer (score 2):

As Marc mentioned, SQL will never guarantee ordering without an `ORDER BY` clause. Historically, cases like this were problematic in Postgres, because you couldn't write an `ORDER BY` which referenced the array index.

They addressed this in 9.4 by adding the `WITH ORDINALITY` clause for set-returning function calls, allowing you to unpack an array into a "values" column and an "index" column:

```
SELECT * FROM table
JOIN UNNEST(<preSortedIds>) WITH ORDINALITY u(id,pos) USING (id)
ORDER BY pos
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, when you want to order a result use, you must use an "ORDER BY" clause.  Else the results are in a inpredictable order.  So rewrite you query as

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = ANY (<preSortedIds>)
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: the idsArray is not in sequential order

Comment: It does not need to be in sequential order.

Comment: I thing I misunderstood you, you want the resulting table to be in the order of the preSortedIds, right?